# Firebird iSQL Output to csv leaving blank rows between records

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a Firebird 2.5 database that I require to export data to csv format.  I have a .SQL file that I call from a .bat file.  It works and exports the data, but the formatting isn't 100%.

When its exporting to csv it is leaving 4 blank rows between each record.  This is my SQL:

```
OUTPUT C:\\SQL_Scripts\\AddrBkExtract.csv FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ',' QUOTE '"';
SELECT a.ID || ';' || a."NAME" || ';' || a.ADDRESS1 || ';' || a.ADDRESS2 || ';' || a.ADDRESS3 || ';' || a.POSTCODE FROM ADDRESSBOOK a;
```

When it exports it gives me data like this:

```
1;Testname;testaddr1;testaddr2;testaddr3;testaddr4;testpostcode




2;Testname;testaddr5;testaddr6;testaddr7;testaddr8;testpostcode
```

But I want it like this:

```
1;Testname;testaddr1;testaddr2;testaddr3;testaddr4;testpostcode
2;Testname;testaddr5;testaddr6;testaddr7;testaddr8;testpostcode
```

Its also exporting the word 'CONCATENATION    ' between rows?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like ISQL script because ISQL has no "format" clause in OUTPUT command. It is rather IBExpert script: https://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/pmwiki.php?n=Doc.ScriptExecutive#Output

Comment: Please confirm which tool you're really using, ISQL or IBExpert. Also if you're using a tool that apparently can specify the format of the separator, why are you injecting your own separator here? It would also be good to know if any of the fields involved are blobs (as that could explain the problem if this is actually ISQL)..

Comment: I can confirm the tool being used is ISQL Version WI-V2.5.2.26540 Firebird 2.5  None of the fields are blobs - they are all varchar except ID which is INT.  My ISQL knowledge is quite limited - I put the above together from various websites and testing

Comment: In short ISQL cannot do what you want. The best you can do with it is "SET HEADING OFF" and cast your fields to VARCHAR that prevent padding but problem with quoting will be still there. Better use IBEScript or https://github.com/mariuz/fbexport

Comment: If it helps, I got this working.  I just import as is into SQL Server in a staging table and cleanup there.  Not ideal as would have preferred to fix it at source.

Comment: use fbexport then

Comment: If your goal is import into MS SQL you don't need CVS at all. Just use Firebird ODBC driver and MS SQL Import/Export Master.

Comment: @user13964273 funny thing is that one can generate quasi-CVS like the select above using Firebird's `EXTERNAL TABLE` without any SQL. It would be a very inefficient one (all rows in ET would have to have fixed length, space-right-padded`) but for a one-time use no one cares. Just add right-padding and `||ASCII_CHAR(13)||ASCII_CHAR(10)` into the given `select`, declare some `external table` consisting of a single `char` (not `varchar`) column of like 400 or maybe 4000 chars length and MBCS enconding (like Windows-1251) and issue a usual insert-from-select. Drop the ET and you have your CSV

Comment: i called that a quasi-CSV because it does not use quotes to enclse string values, and **violating** what CSV is he does not use COMMAs - but Microsoft is know for obsessively violating standards.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the empty lines in Firebird 2.5.9. It is possible this is some bug in Firebird 2.5.2, so you could try upgrading, though a quick scan of the [release notes](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/2_5/rlsnotes25.html) doesn't show anything like this.

Without example data to reproduce this it is hard to guess about the cause of the additional empty lines between the rows, but possibly `POSTCODE` contains linebreaks. A potential solution could be to [`TRIM`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-functions-string.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-trim) each column before concatenation, or at least the `POSTCODE` column.

As mentioned in the comments by Arioch 'The, you can prevent the `CONCATENATION` column header from appearing by using the [`SET HEADING OFF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-set-heading) command.

As an aside, the ISQL [`OUTPUT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-command-output) command only takes a file name, it does not have a `FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ',' QUOTE '"'` clause. You likely picked this up from a different tool than ISQL (the comments suggest IBExpert script). This is silently ignored, because ISQL considered the filename to be complete after the first space (filenames with spaces need to be surrounded by single or double quotes), and ignores everything else until the terminator.

Comment: Thanks for the info - the SET HEADING OFF removed the word CONCATENATION and I've tried TRIM but still getting 4 blank rows after each record.  Not to worry, I'm cleaning it all up via SSIS

Comment: With SSIS you can use ODBC or .NET sources directly AFAIK. @Michael

Comment: it appears only if its on the same bitness - we are using 32-bit Firebird database and our SQL environment is 100% 64 bit

Comment: @Michael The bitness of your Firebird database is not relevant, however you must install the 64-bit client libraries (using the 64-bit Firebird installer), and install the 64-bit Firebird ODBC driver.

Comment: for one time use you perhaps can also try Firebird .Net provider (if MS SQL is capable ofconnecting to dot-net data sources) or commercial ibprovider.com in trial mode. ODBC seems to be little maintained so i have some reservations about it.